# Flask url_for URLs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, flask

What is the recommended way to create dynamic URLs in Javascript files when using flask? In the jinja2 templates and within the python views `url_for` is used, what is the recommended way to do this in `.js` files? Since they are not interpreted by the template engine.

What basically want to do is:

```
// in comments.js
$.post(url_for('comment.comment_reply'));
```

Which is not possible.

But naturally, I can execute that in a template:

```
<script>
    $.post(url_for('comment.comment_reply'));
</script>
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

What @dumbmatter's suggesting is pretty much considered a de facto standard way. But I thought there would be a nicer way of doing it. So I managed to develop this plugin: [Flask-JSGlue](http://stewartpark.github.io/Flask-JSGlue/).

After adding `{{ JSGlue.include() }}`, you can do the following in your source code:

```
<script>
    $.post(Flask.url_for('comment.comment_reply', {article_id: 3}));
</script>
```

or:

```
<script>
    location.href = Flask.url_for('index', {});
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I was looking for in 2012. :) I'll change the accepted answer as this is a lot nicer

Comment: Does this allow you to use javascript variables at page-runtime to specify parameters to url_for of building the url?  Is that what the article_id in your example code signifies?

Comment: Yes, @ThatAintWorking. This can be used as exactly the same as what you would use in the view functions on Flask. And it is a client-side implementation.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have come back and removed or updated my comment. I posted it before really checking out your library. I'm already using it in my project. Thanks for making it.

Comment: I love the idea of this! I couldn't get it working; I passed the jsglue variable in the render_template method and then added this `{{ JSGlue.include() }}`, but when I tried to use `Flask.url_for()` in my javascript, I got `Uncaught ReferenceError: Flask is not defined`. It is completely possible that I missed something though. Anyways, good stuff!

Comment: @tmthyjames You don't have to pass it in the render_template method; you just create the JSGlue instance with the Flask app instance and use it directly from templates. `JSGlue.include()` just adds a `<script>` tag to include the `Flask` javascript object in the front-end side. Hope you'd get it working!

Comment: This is very nice solution. I couldn't change script file path, which in my case was `d3.json("{{url_for('static', filename='userdata/0af968589866013dbe09f57d3c78cc094666ff49.json')}}", ` because file path information is inside `{{ url_for }}` command, so I couldn't break. However, now I can define var `usermusics` as `0afblahblah.json` and use it like  `Flask.url_for("static", {"filename": usermusics})`

Comment: This looks really convenient, but has anybody considered the security implications of exposing this part of the Flask API to the public?

Comment: This is actually potentially even worse: It actually *lists all your endpoints* and information about their parameters in the JS file.

Comment: This could be improved significantly if it only included endpoints whitelisted by a decorator.

Comment: Decorator sounds like a good idea. But to be fair, having an endpoint not exposed doesn't make it secure. You have to have some kind of authentication/security other than just not exposing endpoints. I'll add this to the roadmap, I think that's a valid/more secure approach. Thanks for the input, @Collin.

Comment: Awesome! Right, I was talking only about endpoints that someone doesn't have access to. That is, ones where they would get a 403/404/redirect-to-login-page if they were to try to access. No reason to list those endpoints publicly, and listing them publicly could make it easier for an adversary to find a security vulnerability if there is one.

Comment: @Collin In security, you generally assume your attacker knows everything about how your system works that you do (note that "how your system works" does exclude secret passwords, keys, etc.). Your system should be secure even if the attacker knows the end points. There are other ways of getting them, e.g. social engineering, infecting a legitimate user's machine, and I'm sure the list goes on. Relying on an attacker not knowing the endpoint is a form of "security through obscurity," and in practice, such techniques generally don't hold up well to a real attacker.

Comment: @Collin Also keep in mind that your URLs are *fundamentally* public information. Many of your users will know them, so they would be difficult to protect anyway. And you're really only exposing a *pattern*, so an attacker still needs the inputs to the pattern. I don't think this small exposure of information greatly increases your risk.

Comment: @jpmc26 You're absolutely right that that's how it should work. Unfortunately, inherited codebases are a thing....

Comment: @Collin That's the point you go to your manager/client and say, "This application as it exists now has fundamental security flaws that should be addressed immediately if you value your reputation. Here is what I propose..."

Comment: I have a question: How would it be possible to integrate Flask-JSGlue not on a standard Flask application but on a socketized Flask-SocketIO application? I'm trying to do so with no luck, I've opened a question for it at this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54310058/integrate-flask-jsglue-on-a-socketized-flask-socketio-application - if anybody knows how to do this, any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 16):

The [Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/jquery/#where-is-my-site) suggests using `url_for` in your HTML file to set a variable containing the root URL that you can access elsewhere. Then, you would have to manually build the view URLs on top of that, although I guess you could store them similar to the root URL.

Comment: Not that pretty, but I guess it will have to do!

Comment: Now that I think about it again, wouldn't it be possible to write a Flask extension that sees the URL routing defined in the Python code and dynamically translates it (whenever something changes) into equivalent JavaScript code, thus providing an equivalent `url_for` in JavaScript?

Comment: Adding a bit more details to the answer would be helpful. I'm doing exactly what the link recommends, but the template variable `request.script_root|tojson|safe` renders to an empty string for me. Unfortunately the doc link doesn't give a self-contained example and I can't figure out what it is assuming implicitly...

Comment: Yup, adding to this, if you are needing a url_for that is specifically for Javascript and doesn't fit into the HTML template, then you should probably be writing a small JS lib to do your AJAX requests. This lib could read the urls from a JSON that is dynamically created by Jinja2

Answer (score 7):

Was searching for a solution, them come up with this solution where

- **No add-on is required**
- **No hard-coding URL**

The key is to realise `Jinja2` has the ability to render javascript out of the box.

---

Setup your template folder to something like below:

```
/template
    /html
        /index.html
    /js
        /index.js
```

---

In your views.py

```
@app.route("/index_js")
def index_js():
    render_template("/js/index.js")
```

---

Now instead of serving the javascript from your static folder. You would use:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('index_js') }}"></script>
```

After all, you are generating the javascript on the fly, it is no longer a static file.

---

Now, inside of you javascript file, simply use the `url_for` as you would in any `html` file.

For example using `Jquery` to make an Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  url: {{ url_for('endpoint_to_resource') }},
  method: "GET",
  success: call_back()
})
```

Comment: I've actually used this solution, but it's important to note the performance impact of rendering all your javascript files with jinja2, and its potential impact on caching.

Comment: Thanks for the alternate solution. Note that you have a typo in your view function. It should be 
```return render_template("/js/index.js")``` rather than ```render_template("/js/index.js")```

Answer (score 3):

@jeremy's answer is correct and probably the more common approach, but as an alternative answer, note that `dantezhu` wrote and published a [flask extension](https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js) that claims to do the exact url-route-map-to-javascript translation suggested in the comment.

Answer (score 2):

I use this dirty and ugly trick:

```
"{{url_for('mypage', name=metadata.name,scale=93,group=2)}}"
.replace('93/group',scale+'/group')
```

where `scale` is the javascript variable I want to use for an AJAX request.
So, url_for generate an URL and JavaScript replace the parameter at runtime. The generated code is something like:

```
"/ajaxservive/mynam/scale/93/group/2".replace('93/group',scale+'/group')
```

which is pretty strange, but still can't find more elegant solutions.

In fact, [looking at the code](https://github.com/dantezhu/flask_util_js/blob/master/flask_util_js.py) of the linked flask extension, it does the same thing but managing the general case.

Answer (score 1):

In my case,
I was trying to dynamically create urls

I solved my issue as follows (Note: I've swapped out Angular's syntax to {[x]}:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="x in projects">
        {[x.title]}
        {% set url = url_for('static',filename="img/") %}

        <img src="{{url}}{[x.img]}">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pass a dynamically created url route to a javascript function by using "tojson" with Jinja2 and Flask.

To pass the dynmaic url from the html template to js, simply add '|tojson' at the end of your jinja statment to convert it to the appropriate format.

Instead of:

```
<script>
 $.post(url_for('comment.comment_reply'));
</script>
```

Try:

```
<script>
 var route = {{ url_for('comment.comment_reply')|tojson }};
 yourJavaScriptFunction(route);
</script>
```

Then you will be able to use the route in your js functions as the correct route for whatever you need.

```
yourJavaScriptFunction(route){
 console.log(route);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I was trying to call a FLASK route when a button is pressed. It should collect the response and update a div. The page should not reload.

I used jquery to do this.

**Here's the code:**

```
@app.route('/<name>')
def getContent(name):
    return 'This is %s' % name
```

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="mySpace" class="my-3">Count</div>

    <button id="next_id" class="btn btn-primary">Press</button>

    <script>
        $('#next_id').click(function (){
            $.get('/aroy', function(data, status){
            $('#mySpace').html(data);
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest this:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.js') }}" type="text/javascript">
</script>
```

Works fine for me