# Integrate Flask-JSGlue on a socketized Flask-SocketIO application

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

**Case 1**

Suppose you have a Python Flask application and you want to socketize it - you do the standard:

```
app = Flask("MyApp")
socketio = SocketIO(app)
```

**Case 2**

Suppose you have a Python Flask application and you want to integrate Flask-JSGlue - https://pypi.org/project/Flask-JSGlue/ - you do the standard:

```
jsglue = JSGlue()
app = Flask("MyApp") 
jsglue.init_app(app)
```

**Case 3 (Question)**

Suppose now you want to integrate Flask-JSGlue on a socketized app - how would you go with this?

I'm trying to understand how can I merge Case 1 and Case 2 in order to obtain a socketized Flask app that integrates Flask-JSGlue.

**What I've tried**

*As a first try* I tried doing:

```
jsglue = JSGlue()
app = Flask("MyApp")
socketio = SocketIO(app)
jsglue.init_app(socketio)
```

But this results in the following error:

> jsglue.init_app(socketio) File
>   "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_jsglue.py", line 31, in init_app
>   @app.route(JSGLUE_JS_PATH) AttributeError: 'SocketIO' object has no
>   attribute 'route'

*As a second try*, as stated also in the comments, I tried doing:

```
jsglue = JSGlue()
app = Flask("MyApp")
socketio = SocketIO(app)
jsglue.init_app(app)
```

Doing so results in program being executed but socketized functions becoming totally unresponsive.

If anybody knows how to do this, that would be great

Comment: Try `jsglue.init_app(app)`, your `socketio` instance has nothing to do there.

Comment: @yorodm doing what you suggests results in program being executed but socketized functions becoming totally unresponsive so I don't think what you suggest solves the issue in any way

Comment: The format suggested by @yorodm is the correct one. Add more information regarding the "socketized functions becoming totally unresponsive". Explain how you start the application, and to what the app fails to respond.